# How can I fill-in this Pentagram?

Tags: graphics

This is my code:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Yellow], Yellow, Polygon[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 4 π, (4 π)/5}]]}]
```

which gives this:

[image]

but I want to get:

[image]

How?

Comment: In  Version 11, your code gives the second image. ($CloudVersion: 1.42.1 (June 5, 2017))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use the undocumented functions `SimplePolygonPartition` and `PolygonCombine`:

```
poly = Polygon[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 4 \[Pi], (4 \[Pi])/5}]];

Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
poly2 = PolygonCombine@SimplePolygonPartition@poly;
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, poly2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Now this is the kind of answer I was hoping for. +1

Comment: Does this also work for 3D polygons? Just tried without success - seems to strip off any surplus dimensions.

Comment: @YvesKlett, I think you've answered your own question :-)

Comment: Ach, I hate being right sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you have overlapping areas. The way this is handled by Mathematica is twice covered it will be negated and not be filled.

You could draw it by creating both the points at the tips and the valleys:

```
 Graphics[{Yellow,
 Polygon[
 Reverse@Riffle[
   Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, (2 π)/5}],
   Table[
    2/(3 + Sqrt[5]) {Cos[t + π/5], Sin[t + π/5]}, {t, 0, 
    2 π, (2 π)/5}]
   ]]
  }]
```

I'm not certain about the scaling factor for the valleys, but it looks close enough.

Comment: The scaling factor is `1/GoldenRatio^2`.

Comment: @KennyColnago Ah yes, so it's 2/(3+Sqrt[5]). I was lazy and had something in the back of my mind telling me it was something with sqrt and 3. So close, yet so far. :)

Comment: Graphics[{Yellow, 
  Polygon[Join @@ 
    Table[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 
      1/2 (3 - Sqrt[5]) {Cos[t + π/5], Sin[t + π/5]}}, 
      {t, 0, 2 π, (2 π)/5}]]}]

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematica 12

```
poly=Polygon[Table[{Cos[t],Sin[t]},{t,0,4π, 4π/5}]];
Graphics[{Yellow,#},PlotRange->1]& /@ {poly,OuterPolygon[poly],InnerPolygon[poly]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Graphics@Polygon@Array[{Sin@#,Cos@#}&[π/5#]If[OddQ@#,3-√5,2]/2&,10] 

Graphics@Polygon@Table[(1-(√5 - 1)/2*Mod[i, 2])*{Cos[π/5i], Sin[π/5i], {i,0,9}]}

Graphics[{Yellow, 
  Polygon[Table[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 4 π, (4 π)/5}]], 
  Polygon[Table[1/2 (3 - Sqrt[5]) {Sin[t + Pi/5], Cos[t + Pi/5]},
{t, 0, 2 π, (2 π)/5}]]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also fill it with a disk. I'm hoping for a less manual answer anyway

```
Graphics[{Yellow, 
  Polygon[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 4 \[Pi], (4 \[Pi])/5}]], 
  Disk[{0, 0}, 1/GoldenRatio^2]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
 ListLinePlot[Table[{Cos@i, Sin@i}, {i, 0, 4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]/5}],
     PlotStyle -> None, Axes -> None, Filling -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     FillingStyle -> Yellow]
```

Comment: Nice example. +1